# Android - Define two buttons next to each other

Tags: android, xml, button

I want to define two buttons , next to each other , by xml , in this style:
https://i.imgsafe.org/8d60c62.png

- How can i do that? thanks.

Comment: You should post code to what you have tried so far. Makes it easier to give you the correct answer, since it's multiple ways to achieve this. Anyway, I gave a simple code snippet below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

<Button
android:layout_width="0"
android:text="button1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"/>


<Button
android:layout_width="0"
android:text="button2"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"/>

/LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a linear layout and set the orientation as horizontal, then create your buttons